# Create custum control styles for modern ui

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, modern-ui

how i can create custum control styles for modern ui firstfloor software ??

to costimaze link color and grouplink color ??

this is my personnel theme code

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/FirstFloor.ModernUI;component/Assets/ModernUI.dark.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<Color x:Key="AccentColor">#0082AD</Color>

<Rectangle x:Key="WindowBackgroundContent" x:Shared="false">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush Opacity="25" ImageSource="/Images/background.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

[image: my programm]

Comment: You should edit ModernUI.dark.xaml file. If you give a link to this file I can help you. Can't find this page on [github](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/tree/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI)

Comment: this is the file [Github](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Shared/Assets/ModernUI.Dark.xaml)

Answer (score 0):

You can open ModernUI.dark.xaml file and set another color in lines:

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Hyperlink" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkHover" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkDisabled" Color="#717171" />
```

Or you can open your project in [Blend](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/designing-your-xaml-ui-with-blend-jump-start-8260)

Comment: but it does not work i can't find where i can change the background of modern tab type ="List"

I'm using Usercontrol 
i add the List code it the topic

Comment: Provide full xaml of your page (or part with this control)

Comment: i can not insert it into the post .. you can get it from here  [text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B67md3zpZJ-YUDRUVjJUZnZXQ2c/view?usp=sharing)